# Confusion about constant pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, constants

For a `const int *ptr`
You cannot change the value pointed by ptr

```
int main()
{
    const int *p;
    int a=5;
    p=&a;   
    printf("%d",++(*p));
}
```

Above program throws me error. which is fair enough.

But why does below code doesn't throw me error.

```
int main()
{
    const int const *p;
    int a=5;
    p=&a;
    a=100;  // changing the content pointed by the constant pointer

    printf("%d",(*p));
}
```

I am changing the value pointed by const pointer. i.e I am changing the value of var a from
5 to 100 ?

Comment: Yeah. Is `a` qualified as `const`? Naw. Then what's the problem? Are you trying to change it through a pointer to `const`? Nope. Then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the statement a = 100; means that you are changing value at 100 using variable a, which is not a constant. So you will be able to change the value of a.

But if you will try to run below code:

```
int main()
{
        const int const *p;
        int a=5;
        p=&a;
        *p=100;
//      a=100;
        printf("(*p)=%d",(*p));
        return 0;
}
```

this will give you error because the pointer using which you are to change value points to a read only location. Because you have declared value at pointer location to be constant.

Here a and p are 2 different variables and they have their own properties.

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'a' is not constant, so you are able to change it's value. const int a = 5; cannot be changed.

The variable 'p' points to the value of 'a' but does not change the variable 'a' to a constant.